# Magento 2 Order Confirmation How to Send Two Email

Tags: magento2, orders, email

I am using Magento 2.1.6, I want to send two different email on order confirmation.

Order confirmation email sent successfully.But how i send my custom another email.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What will be the content on your second email?

Comment: It is for send some another order information and payment link

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a second email field in customer account area.  Then providing this has a value then order confirmation will be cc'd to this addresses

I put together an extension

https://github.com/DominicWatts/EmailCC

[image: Email CC field]

One minor note.  Amazon payment seemed to get in the way.  So I had to override the default functionality.  Not cleanest solution.  Basically `<referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">` didn't seem to want to work.  If you take a look at phtml you will see what I've done.

Comment: Hello @Dominic Xigen, Thank you for your answer.I want to send the 2 different order email to the customer